# Google Timeline broken?

Tags: maps, timeline

I can load Google Maps on my Windows 11 laptop using Chrome.  However, when I try to look at my timeline I get an error:
Error 400

400. That’s an error.

Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know.

https://www.google.com/maps/timeline?hl=en&authuser=0&ei=wsixY6jUM4rOwbkPqYmR0Ak%3A21&ved=1t%3A17706

Is this a known issue?

Stop/start Chrome and Maps.  Checked maps status page and no errors showing

Answer (score 0):

Today I noticed that the google timeline stopped working as soon as I enter Macao SAR (China). Use internet through VPN in Hong Kong and it works again.

So in my personal situation, I'd think google timeline is disabled in this part of the world.